# Is my CSS code not set up correctly for media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Ok so first off I apologise if my title is not very clear! I'm fairly new to css and currently following the landing page project with freecodecamp, I'm at the point where I wanted to start adding media queries to my code (maybe should have added them as I went along). I'm using there example code as a reference to see what I should be doing, but it just seems that no matter what media queries I add the page doesn't respond how I expect it too, or it just messes up the whole css code!

Here is a link to my codepen - https://codepen.io/rorymx/pen/XWmbbzY
and this is some of the html and css from it.

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header id="header">
    <div id="img-div">
      <img id="header-img" src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/2d/50/8b/2d508b7019bf7b8711673825c7bd3252.jpg">
    </div>

    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a> </li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#how-it-works">How it works</a> </li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>
</div>
```

please ignore the look its just temporary as the code is mainly what I'm playing about with.

For example. one of the media queries i was trying to add was

```
@media (max-width: 650px) header{flex-wrap: wrap;}
```

to the header

```
@media (max-width: 650px) {
nav {
margin-top: 10px;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
padding: 0 50px;
}
}
```

which i got from the example code, which i played about with but it just seemed to mess everything up!

If anyone could shed some light as why this may be happening, or if i've not set some things up properly, or if the code is just complete rubbish and needs starting again!

Comment: note: your section for the features is mis-spelt (as 'secton' - without the 'i')  - just an addendum

Comment: @Jack Note: the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: @Jack That doesn't do it. While it's allowed for "not breaking the old web" reasons, it has no meaning, it does nothing, and browsers are instructed to ignore it. So doing so is pointless and useless.

Comment: Do you have `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">` in your header?

Comment: @Jack My point is, it's unspecified in HTML and useless so why use it? There is no reason.

Comment: @Rob, I see and I understand. Shall we remove our comments and put this behind us?

Comment: @RachelGallen Thank you for spotting the spelling mistake!

Comment: @Jack Thanks I will have a look into that!

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a media query in the code example that you provided via the Codepen link (https://codepen.io/rorymx/pen/XWmbbzY) that you have provided. So, the question seems a bit unclear.

That said, from the way the code looks that you have included in your description above in addition to the context that you've provided from the code that you included from your Codepen link ... it could potentially be something as simple as the way you're selecting the nav element, but I can't say this conclusively with the information given.

What I will say, however, is that if I add the following code to the bottom of the stylesheet you have provided from Codepen, it works great! Here's what I wrote:

```
body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  backgroun-color: 
}

#wrapper{
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

#header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

#img-div{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;  
}


#header-img{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  left: 25%;
}

#nav-bar > ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  float: right;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 30vw;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#body{
  flex: 1;
  display: block;
  background-color: #B2B2B2;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
}

#title{
  text-align: center;
}

#submit-sec{
  margin: 10px;
  display:flex;
  justfy-content: center;
  flex-directon: column;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto; 
}

#email{
  width: 25vw;
  height: 10vh;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#submit{
 background-color: yellow;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 width: 50%;
 margin: 10px 0px;
}

#submit:hover{
  background-color: #C4C100 ;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#features{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
}

 .feature-div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: left;
    width: 60vw;  
    margin: 15px 0px;
  }

.feature-div > h2{
  margin: 2px 0px;
}

.feature-div > p{
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 2px 0px;
}

#how-it-works{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

iframe{
  max-width: 540px;
  width: 100vw;
}

#pricing{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

.price-sec{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
 width: calc(100% / 3);
 border: 2px solid #000000;
 margin: 50px;
 padding: 0px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 background-color: #FBEDA6;
}

.price-sec > .price-head{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.price-sec > ol{
  padding: 0px;
}

ol > li{
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 2px;
}

.price-sec > button{
  border: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #FD0008;
  color: white;
}

.price-sec > button:hover{
  background-color: #971B1B;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#footer{
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
}

#footer > ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 5px;
}

#footer > ul > li{
  margin: 0px 5px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

#footer > span{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
}


@media (max-width: 600px) {
  nav {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Adding my test code seems to work fine from a technical standpoint since a part of the nav element changes its background color from transparent to red when I shrink the window down smaller than a width of 600px as reflected by the media query I wrote. As for the code that you have provided, I was able to successfully add that code as well in the following way:

```
body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  backgroun-color: 
}

#wrapper{
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

#header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

#img-div{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;  
}


#header-img{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  left: 25%;
}

#nav-bar > ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  float: right;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 30vw;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#body{
  flex: 1;
  display: block;
  background-color: #B2B2B2;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
}

#title{
  text-align: center;
}

#submit-sec{
  margin: 10px;
  display:flex;
  justfy-content: center;
  flex-directon: column;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto; 
}

#email{
  width: 25vw;
  height: 10vh;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#submit{
 background-color: yellow;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 width: 50%;
 margin: 10px 0px;
}

#submit:hover{
  background-color: #C4C100 ;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#features{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
}

 .feature-div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: left;
    width: 60vw;  
    margin: 15px 0px;
  }

.feature-div > h2{
  margin: 2px 0px;
}

.feature-div > p{
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 2px 0px;
}

#how-it-works{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

iframe{
  max-width: 540px;
  width: 100vw;
}

#pricing{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

.price-sec{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
 width: calc(100% / 3);
 border: 2px solid #000000;
 margin: 50px;
 padding: 0px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 background-color: #FBEDA6;
}

.price-sec > .price-head{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.price-sec > ol{
  padding: 0px;
}

ol > li{
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 2px;
}

.price-sec > button{
  border: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #FD0008;
  color: white;
}

.price-sec > button:hover{
  background-color: #971B1B;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#footer{
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
}

#footer > ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 5px;
}

#footer > ul > li{
  margin: 0px 5px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

#footer > span{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
}


@media (max-width: 650px) {
  nav {
    background-color: red;
  }

  header {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  nav {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 50px;
  }
}
```

If you add this code to your stylesheet in the Codepen that you have provided, you will see that the code is in fact working the way it is written. As far as what you wish to achieve, however, this may not be the solution that you are looking for. With a little more guidance on what the end result you wish to achieve is, I'm happy to continue to guide and help where I can.

Try this:

```
@media (max-width: 650px) {
    #nav-bar > ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. Yeah I took the media queries out of my code on codepen as it seemed to be just messing things up. Yes brilliant thats along the lines of what im wanting it to do, but may I ask how to make the nav links at the top stack on top of each other like a normal list? I was hoping to make this happen at about 850px with the links staying at the top right corner, then once it reaches the 650px mark for them to stay in that format and then drop underneath the logo like your example! Hope that makes sense to you!

Comment: You should be able to achieve stacking on the (parent) container by adding flex-box properties and values that change the layout as you want it to be. Try flex-direction: column; on the parent container’s selector, #nav-bar > ul inside of a media query with a max-width of 650 pixels.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was actually able to figure it out and yes it was along them lines! The other question I did have (sorry if im asking too many) is with the header image. Im trying to get it to center within its div with media query at 650px, the nav bar wrap underneath it nicely, but for some reason when ever I give the image either an auto margin or various code to align it to center. But it seems it then jumps slightly to right of center?